# How can i access a Model in another Namespace in Zend2?

Tags: php, model, namespaces, instance

i am new to zend2, i have created a model(class) in a namespace, and i want to make an instance of this model within a controller from another namespace , so do you know how can i do this?

Thanks
Tarek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put classes names and namespaces here. Of course, you can create class from another namespace, all you need is to use that namespace. E.g

```
   $x = new MyNamespace\SuperClass\Hello\MySuperClass();
   ----     <---------namespace---------><-className--->
```

to avoid writing each time whole namespace, you can use `use` at beginning of the script

```
namespace currentNamespace;

use MyNamespace\SuperClass\Hello;

class myClass() {
    public function something() {
        $x = new MySuperClass(); // instead of MyNamespace\SuperClass\Hello\MySuperClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: hello @szapio,
i tried your answer, but i got an error:
I wrote:

namespace Desktop\Controller;
use Application\Model\User;

class myClass() {
    public function something() {
       $User =  User();
    }
}

But i got this error :

Fatal error: Call to undefined function Desktop\Controller\User()

Comment: of course i forgot  key word `new` before class name :D i fixed my code :) now should work! Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution as following:
in Module.php i should register my Model(class):

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(

        'invokables' => array(
            'User' => 'Application\Model\User'
        ),            
    );
}
```

and later when i want to use it within another class i call it this way:

$User = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('User');

Comment: But this call used in a Controller, but do anyone know, how to do that within a Model from another class, not controller ?!

Comment: Look my example i made a mistake but i fixed it.